# Get last key-value pair in PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that is structured like this:

```
[33] => Array
    (
        [time] => 1285571561
        [user] => test0
    )

[34] => Array
    (
        [time] => 1285571659
        [user] => test1
    )

[35] => Array
    (
        [time] => 1285571682
        [user] => test2
    )
```

How can I get the last value in the array, but maintaining the index [35]?

The outcome that I am looking for is this:

```
[35] => Array
    (
        [time] => 1285571682
        [user] => test2
    )
```

Comment: couse i have a little shoutbox, file-based, and want to show only one shout, file is serialized.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

try to use

```
end($array);
```

Comment: This is the best way to get the _value_ of the last array element, but the OP asks for an array containing only the last element (with its proper index). However, +1 as this is what _most people_ googling this will need.

Comment: The OP explicitly asked ***... but maintaining the index [35]?***. The OP repeats this wish in the comment on Gumbo's answer. I think therefore it is misleading that this answer is selected as the accepted answer. The answer of @salathe best describes the behavior the OP asked for.

Answer (score 68):

```
$last = array_slice($array, -1, 1, true);
```

See http://php.net/array_slice for details on what the arguments mean.

P.S. Unlike the other answers, this one actually does what you want. :-)

Comment: But this return other array not just the string

Comment: +1 This actually does what the question asked - it preserves the index and returns an array with a single element (which is what was implied by the example in the question).

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`end`](http://php.net/end) to advance the internal pointer to the end or [`array_slice`](http://php.net/array_slice) to get an array only containing the last element:

```
$last = end($arr);
$last = current(array_slice($arr, -1));
```

Comment: but i need to preserve the index, like:[35] => Array
    (
        [time] => 1285571682
        [user] => test2
    )

Comment: If you need to preserve the index, you could use array_slice(). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801891/get-last-value-in-array/3802007#3802007

Answer (score 4):

If you have an array

```
$last_element = array_pop(array);
```

Answer (score 3):

**Example 1:**

```
$arr = array("a"=>"a", "5"=>"b", "c", "key"=>"d", "lastkey"=>"e");
print_r(end($arr));
```

**Output** = e

---

**Example 2:**

ARRAY **without** key(s)

```
$arr = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");
print_r(array_slice($arr, -1, 1, true));
// output is = array( [4] => e )
```

---

**Example 3:**

ARRAY **with** key(s)

```
$arr = array("a"=>"a", "5"=>"b", "c", "key"=>"d", "lastkey"=>"e");
print_r(array_slice($arr, -1, 1, true));
// output is = array ( [lastkey] => e )
```

---

**Example 4:**

If your array keys like : [0] [1] [2] [3] [4] ... etc. You can use this:

```
$arr = array("a","b","c","d","e");
$lastindex = count($arr)-1;
print_r($lastindex);
```

**Output** = 4

---

**Example 5:**
But if you are not sure!

```
$arr = array("a"=>"a", "5"=>"b", "c", "key"=>"d", "lastkey"=>"e");
$ar_k = array_keys($arr);
$lastindex = $ar_k [ count($ar_k) - 1 ];
print_r($lastindex);
```

**Output** = lastkey

---

### Resources:

1. https://php.net/array_slice
2. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php
3. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php
4. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php

Answer (score 2):

Like said Gumbo,

```
<?php

$fruits = array('apple', 'banana', 'cranberry');
echo end($fruits); // cranberry

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution cold be:

```
$value = $arr[count($arr) - 1];
```

The above will count the amount of array values, substract 1 and then return the value.

Note: This can only be used if your array keys are numeric.

Answer (score 0):

As the key is needed, the accepted solution doesn't work.

This:

```
end($array);
return array(key($array) => array_pop($array));
```

will return exactly as the example in the question.

Answer (score 0):

`"SPL-way"`:

```
$splArray = SplFixedArray::fromArray($array);
$last_item_with_preserved_index[$splArray->getSize()-1] = $splArray->offsetGet($splArray->getSize()-1);
```

Read more about `SplFixedArray` and why it's in some cases ( especially with big-index sizes array-data) more preferable than basic `array` here => [The SplFixedArray class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php).