# how to get the last entry from an array in cakephp 2.3

Tags: php

I am having problem finding the last record from an array in cakephp. Please suggest me a proper way to find out the last entry from the array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [get last value in array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801891/get-last-value-in-array)

Comment: 'PassportDetail' => array(
  (int) 0 => array(
   'id' => '3',
   'iso_countrylist_id' => '154',
   'passport_number' => 'gdfgdfsgfdg',
   'issue_date' => '2014-07-25',
   'expiry_date' => '2014-07-25',
   'basic_info_id' => '12',
   'IsoCountrylist' => array(
    'title' => 'NEPAL'
   )
  ),
  (int) 1 => array(
   'id' => '4',
   'iso_countrylist_id' => '1',
   'passport_number' => '11111111111',
   'issue_date' => '2014-08-02',
   'expiry_date' => '2014-08-02',
   'basic_info_id' => '12',
   'IsoCountrylist' => array(
    'title' => 'AFGHANISTAN'
   )
  )
 ), I need to echo afghanistan

Answer (score 2):

Same as any other array:

```
$result = end($array);
```