# get last element of array in php which not blank

Tags: php, arrays

I have issue with the **PHP Array**. I want to get the last element from array which is not `null` or not blank.

```
        $string  = '9580 County Road
                    Clarence Center, New York 14032 
                    TEL: 716-863-4133
                    FAX: 716-741-4810 
                    <a href="mailto:rschaefer@wmssales.com">rschaefer@wmssales.com</a>
                    <a href="http://www.wmssales.org" target="_blank">wmssales.org</a>
                    Randy Schaefer';
        $array=explode("\n",$string);
        $new_array = array_filter($array);
        $rev_new_array=array_reverse($new_array);
        for( $i = 0; $i < sizeof($rev_new_array); $i++)
        {
            if($rev_new_array[$i]!="")
            {
                echo $writter = $rev_new_array[$i];break;
            }
        }
```

when i search on google, I find some below link, but which is not useful for me :-

- [`end()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php)
- [get last value in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801891/get-last-value-in-array)
- [Best way to get last element of an array w/o deleting it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687358/best-way-to-get-last-element-of-an-array-w-o-deleting-it)

Comment: What you have is rather inelegant, but should work. What's the problem with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

Your string contains space characters at the end.

So, you need to trim it.

```
<?php
$string  = '9580 County Road
                        Clarence Center, New York 14032 
                        TEL: 716-863-4133
                        FAX: 716-741-4810 
                        <a href="mailto:rschaefer@wmssales.com">rschaefer@wmssales.com</a>
                        <a href="http://www.wmssales.org" target="_blank">wmssales.org</a>
                        Randy Schaefer
                          ';
$string = trim($string);
$array=explode("\n",$string);
echo '<pre>';
print_r(end($new_array))
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

[Working Demo](http://codepad.org/TyhDrPoD#output)

Comment: Thank you much for save my time I already invest 1 hour on this problem. I also use `trim()`, but in my case i use into the `for` loop

Comment: accepting time is 10 min and you are superfast for answering